# how can make transparent proxy on more than one port?

Tags: centos, iptables, transparent-proxy

i want to make transparent proxy with linux ( centos) ,

i want  all incoming connection on port 1000 - 2000 on eth0  forward to  eth1 on port 1000 - 2000 in transparent mode

i have 2 server 
1- linux ( proxy server) 
2- windows

i want protect my windows server with my linux server firewall
also i must make transparent proxy with my linux  server
linux server have 2 interface one for public network an another for private network connected to windows server

so all incoming connection must connect to the linux server (at eth0 public network) first and after checking , must forward to the windows server on private network (with linux interface eth1 )

i can use squid for making transparent proxy but i dont know how i must config the squid for multi port because i want listen in more than 1000 ports

for example from port 1000 to 2000

anyone know how can i do ?

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve? (**Why** do you want to do this? - What is the end goal?) -- [Context is important, and relevant](http://www.bsd-box.net/~mikeg/context).

Comment: i have 2 server 
1- linux ( proxy server) 
2- windows

i want protect my windows server with my linux server firewall
so i must make transparent proxy with my linux  server

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 1000:2000 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 1000:2000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.3
```

Comment: when i try to do that face me this error : iptables: Unknown error 4294967295